# Trying to use powershell to put files in folders based on their extension and the name of the folder

Tags: powershell

I have a directory with three files: .xlsx, .docx, and .txt, I also have folders in that same directory called xlsx, docx and txt.  Basically trying to put each file into its corresponding folder, as a way to practice my PowerShell skills.  I'm very new to PowerShell and have tried the following.  I can tell its wrong, but I'm not quite sure why.

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory
$files = Get-ChildItem -File
foreach ($file in $files) {
        foreach ($folder in $folders) {
                 if ("*$file.extension*" -like "*$folder.Name*") {
                         move-item $file -Destination "C:\Users\userA\Desktop\$folder.name"
                 }
         }
}
```

Comment: what is it doing? how does that NOT match what you expect? are there any errors? i can see what looks like one big gotcha that is repeated 3 times ... [*grin*]

Comment: for some nifty ideas on this project, take a look at this thread >>> `[Challenge] Sorting Files 2 : PowerShell — https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7fno88/challenge_sorting_files_2/` <<<

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below. With the `Where-Object` function, you find the corresponding file. I remove the dot because it is included in the extension otherwise.

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory

$files = Get-ChildItem -File

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $folder = $folders | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like $file.Extension.Replace(".","") }
    Move-Item -Path $file -Destination $folder
}
```

In your example, be careful how your strings are actually been interpreted. If you have `"*$item.Name*"` the string actually "* *variable*.Name*". In this case you need to use `"*$($var.Name)*"` in order to get the correct string.

Comment: Wow, such an elegant solution.  It worked like a charm, thank you.  The thing that was really throwing me off is thinking that name property of the folder could not be compared to the extension property of the file because they're two different types of objects, but -like just compares them as strings/text essentially?

Comment: @Picayuni, yes, `-like` compares two strings but be aware what the content of both strings are.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some adjustments to your approach that make it work. Breaking the -Destination parameter out to a separate variable $newpath lets you set a debug statement there so you can easily examine what it's creating.

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Directory
$files = Get-ChildItem -File
foreach ($file in $files) {
        foreach ($folder in $folders) {
                 if ($file.extension.trim(".") -like $folder.Name) {
                         $newpath = ("{0}\{1}" -f $folder.FullName, $file.Name)
                         move-item $file -Destination $newpath
                 }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could even create target folders for extensions if they do not exist yet:

```
$SourceFolder = C:\sample
$TargetFolder = D:\sample

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -File |
    ForEach-Object{
        $DesinationFolder = Join-Path -Path $TargetFolder -ChildPath $_.Extension.TrimStart('.')
        if(-not (Test-Path -Path $DesinationFolder)){
            New-Item -Path $DesinationFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
        }
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $DesinationFolder -Force 
    }
```